# How do you compare just the time of a Date in Swift?

Tags: swift, sorting, date, datetime, time

I have two Date Objects:

1. `2017-01-13 11:40:17 +0000`
2. `2016-03-15 10:22:14 +0000`

I need to compare just the time of these values and ignore the date

example: 12:00am and 12:01am, 12:01 is later so (12:01am > 12:00am) == true

Comment: What does "compare" mean?

Comment: see which one is bigger or smaller, added example

Comment: are they date object or string ??

Comment: they are Date Objects

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**This is the route I took in the end, which makes it easy to compare just the time of a Date in swift**

New Object Time:

```
class Time: Comparable, Equatable {
init(_ date: Date) {
    //get the current calender
    let calendar = Calendar.current

    //get just the minute and the hour of the day passed to it
    let dateComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: date)

        //calculate the seconds since the beggining of the day for comparisions
        let dateSeconds = dateComponents.hour! * 3600 + dateComponents.minute! * 60

        //set the varibles
        secondsSinceBeginningOfDay = dateSeconds
        hour = dateComponents.hour!
        minute = dateComponents.minute!
    }

    init(_ hour: Int, _ minute: Int) {
        //calculate the seconds since the beggining of the day for comparisions
        let dateSeconds = hour * 3600 + minute * 60

        //set the varibles
        secondsSinceBeginningOfDay = dateSeconds
        self.hour = hour
        self.minute = minute
    }

    var hour : Int
    var minute: Int

    var date: Date {
        //get the current calender
        let calendar = Calendar.current

        //create a new date components.
        var dateComponents = DateComponents()

        dateComponents.hour = hour
        dateComponents.minute = minute

        return calendar.date(byAdding: dateComponents, to: Date())!
    }

    /// the number or seconds since the beggining of the day, this is used for comparisions
    private let secondsSinceBeginningOfDay: Int

    //comparisions so you can compare times
    static func == (lhs: Time, rhs: Time) -> Bool {
        return lhs.secondsSinceBeginningOfDay == rhs.secondsSinceBeginningOfDay
    }

    static func < (lhs: Time, rhs: Time) -> Bool {
        return lhs.secondsSinceBeginningOfDay < rhs.secondsSinceBeginningOfDay
    }

    static func <= (lhs: Time, rhs: Time) -> Bool {
        return lhs.secondsSinceBeginningOfDay <= rhs.secondsSinceBeginningOfDay
    }


    static func >= (lhs: Time, rhs: Time) -> Bool {
        return lhs.secondsSinceBeginningOfDay >= rhs.secondsSinceBeginningOfDay
    }


    static func > (lhs: Time, rhs: Time) -> Bool {
        return lhs.secondsSinceBeginningOfDay > rhs.secondsSinceBeginningOfDay
    }
}
```

Date Extension for easy access:
    //Adds ability to just get the time from a date:

```
extension Date {
    var time: Time {
        return Time(self)
    }
}
```

Example:

```
let firstDate = Date()
let secondDate = firstDate

//Will return true
let timeEqual = firstDate.time == secondDate.time
```

Comment: I was too lazy to implement this. Thanks :')

Answer (score 15):

Much simpler than accepted answer:

**SWIFT 4**

```
// date1 and date2 are the dates you want to compare

let calendar = Calendar.current

var newDate = Date(TimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 0) // Initiates date at 2001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000
var newDate1 = Date(TimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 0) // Same as above

// Recieving the components from the dates you want to compare 
let newDateComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: date1)!
let newDate1Components = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: date2)!

// Adding those components
newDate = calendar.date(byAdding: newDateComponents, to: newDate)
newDate1 = calendar.date(byAdding: newDate1Components, to: newDate1)
```

Answer (score 9):

My approach would be to use [`Calendar`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/calendar) to make them `Date` objects with the same day and then comparing them using for example [`timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/date/1780268-timeintervalsincereferencedate).

Another, cleaner (but most likely with more lines of resulting code) would be to create extension for `Date` called `secondsFromBeginningOfTheDay() -> TimeInterval` and then comparing the resulting double values.

Example based on the second approach:

```
// Creating Date from String
let textDate1 = "2017-01-13T12:21:00-0800"
let textDate2 = "2016-03-06T20:12:05-0900"

let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZ"
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
    return formatter
} ()

// Dates used for the comparison
let date1 = dateFormatter.date(from: textDate1)
let date2 = dateFormatter.date(from: textDate2)




// Date extensions
extension Date {
    func secondsFromBeginningOfTheDay() -> TimeInterval {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        // omitting fractions of seconds for simplicity
        let dateComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .second], from: self)

        let dateSeconds = dateComponents.hour! * 3600 + dateComponents.minute! * 60 + dateComponents.second!

        return TimeInterval(dateSeconds)
    }

    // Interval between two times of the day in seconds
    func timeOfDayInterval(toDate date: Date) -> TimeInterval {
        let date1Seconds = self.secondsFromBeginningOfTheDay()
        let date2Seconds = date.secondsFromBeginningOfTheDay()
        return date2Seconds - date1Seconds
    }
}

if let date1 = date1, let date2 = date2 {
    let diff = date1.timeOfDayInterval(toDate: date2)

    // as text
    if diff > 0 {
        print("Time of the day in the second date is greater")
    } else if diff < 0 {
        print("Time of the day in the first date is greater")
    } else {
        print("Times of the day in both dates are equal")
    }


    // show interval as as H M S
    let timeIntervalFormatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
    timeIntervalFormatter.unitsStyle = .abbreviated
    timeIntervalFormatter.allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute, .second]
    print("Difference between times since midnight is", timeIntervalFormatter.string(from: diff) ?? "n/a")

}

// Output: 
// Time of the day in the second date is greater
// Difference between times since midnight is 8h 51m 5s
```

Answer (score 8):

My solution for comparing two times of day while ignoring the date:

```
let date1 = some time as a date
let date2 = some other time as a date

let time1 = 60*Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: date1!) + Calendar.current.component(.minute, from: date1!)
let time2 =  60*Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: date2!) + Calendar.current.component(.minute, from: date2!)
```

Now you can compare the integers time1 and time2 without regard to the day.  You could add the seconds/60 if you need more precision.

Answer (score 7):

This code works, check it easily in playground

```
let s1 = "22:31"
let s2 = "14:31"
let f = DateFormatter()
f.dateFormat = "HH:mm"

f.date(from: s1)! //"Jan 1, 2000 at 10:31 PM"
f.date(from: s2)! //"Jan 1, 2000 at 2:31 PM"
f.date(from: s1)! > f.date(from: s2)!  // true
```

Comment: please answer with proper description

Comment: I personally do a form of this. To me, it's the cleanest way and since I have an App-wide DateFormatter I'm not making one each time.

Answer (score 3):

There's no standard type for a time-of-day. A reasonable type to start with is just a tuple:

```
typealias TimeOfDay = (hour: Int, minute: Int, second: Int)
```

To create these `TimeOfDay` values, you'll need a `Calendar`. By default, a `Calendar` uses the device's system-wide time zone. If you don't want that, set the `Calendar`'s time zone explicitly. Example:

```
var calendar = Calendar.autoupdatingCurrent
calendar.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")!
```

Now you can use a `DateFormatter` to convert strings to `Date`s (if necessary), and then use `calendar` to extract the time-of-day components from the `Date`s:

```
let strings: [String] = ["2017-01-13 11:40:17 +0000", "2016-03-15 10:22:14 +0000"]
let parser = DateFormatter()
parser.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"
let timesOfDay: [TimeOfDay] = strings.map({ (string) -> TimeOfDay in
    let components = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .second], from: parser.date(from: string)!)
    return (hour: components.hour!, minute: components.minute!, second: components.second!)
})

Swift.print(timesOfDay)
// Output: [(11, 40, 17), (10, 22, 14)]
```

Finally, you can compare these `TimeOfDay` values. Swift comes with standard comparison operators for tuples whose elements are `Comparable`, so this `TimeOfDay` type qualifies. You can just say this:

```
if timesOfDay[0] < timesOfDay[1] {
    Swift.print("date[0] comes first")
} else if timesOfDay[0] == timesOfDay[1] {
    Swift.print("times are equal")
} else {
    Swift.print("date[1] comes first")
}
```

Comment: would this account for am/pm cross over, example 1.00 pm is later then 11:00 am?

Comment: Yes, because 1 pm is represented as 13 in the `hour` element of the tuple.

Comment: Note that the string-dates in your question don't mention am/pm, so I assume they use 24-hour time.

Answer (score 3):

Let say we got two dates in string format:

```
// "2017-01-13 11:40:17 +0000"
// "2016-03-15 10:22:14 +0000"
```

We need to convert this strings to Date format, we create DateFormatter() and set the format ("yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ssZ") it gonna convert

```
//date formatter converts string to date in our case
let firstDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
firstDateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ssZ"
```

Now we can get our date from string to Date format

```
   //convert string to dates
    if let date1 = firstDateFormatter.date(from: "2017-01-13 09:40:17 +0000"),
        let date2 = firstDateFormatter.date(from: "2016-03-15 10:22:14 +0000") {
```

What we want is to compare only Hours and Minutes. So change dateformat to "HH:mm"

```
//we ve got the dates, now switch dateformat for other job
firstDateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
```

Now get the string value from our date, that only contain "HH:mm"

```
   // convert date to string ( part of string we want to compare )
        let HHmmDate1 = firstDateFormatter.string(from: date1) //"17:40"
        let HHmmDate2 = firstDateFormatter.string(from: date2) //"18:22"
```

Final step is to get date from our "HH:mm" values, let say we ask DateFormatter to give us a date, based on time only, in our case "17:40" and "18:22". DateFormatter will put some values for dates, so we get Jan 1, 2000 automatically for both dates, but it will get the time we provide.

```
   //produce "default" dates with desired HH:mm
    //default means same date, but time is different
        let HH1 = firstDateFormatter.date(from: HHmmDate1) //"Jan 1, 2000 at 5:40 PM"
        let HH2 = firstDateFormatter.date(from: HHmmDate2) //"Jan 1, 2000 at 6:22 PM"
```

Now we could easily compare dates

```
 //compare
        HH1! > HH2!
}
```

There are many options to compare dates with Calendar also

Comment: @quicklikerabbit  done! Feel free to ask questions if something not clear

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple in Swift if you use [Swifter Swift](https://github.com/SwifterSwift/SwifterSwift)

```
date1.day = 1
date1.month = 1
date1.year = 2000

date2.day = 1
date2.month = 1
date2.year = 2000
```

now you can use >,<,== operators on date1 and date2 to compare just the time components.

edit - you could do this your self by extending the date class, for example swifter-swift does the bellow for the day component.

```
public var day: Int {
        get {
            return Calendar.current.component(.day, from: self)
        }
        set {
            let allowedRange = Calendar.current.range(of: .day, in: .month, for: self)!
            guard allowedRange.contains(newValue) else { return }

            let currentDay = Calendar.current.component(.day, from: self)
            let daysToAdd = newValue - currentDay
            if let date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: daysToAdd, to: self) {
                self = date
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't work in swift, you can't just set day, month and year from the date object. On the right track though

Comment: yes. you are correct. I am using this code in our production code.. but we are using swifter-swift extension.. )))