# How to compare AM PM in swift

Tags: swift, datetime

I hardly try but can't find how to compare am and pm.

```
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        formatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
        formatter.amSymbol = "AM"
        formatter.pmSymbol = "PM"
        dateString = formatter.string(from: Date())

        // date Format
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = DateFormatter.Style.none;
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.medium;
        currentDate = dateFormatter.string(from: now);

        if self.dateString >= "09:00 AM" { return true }
```

Comment: Your question is pretty confusing. You said _it's working fine_ , so what problems are you facing?

Comment: What do you mean by comparing _AM and PM_ .  What do you want to achieve at last?

Comment: You have to compare *dates*, not their string representations.

Comment: simple logic like if "12:00 AM" >= "09:00 PM" { return true } else { return false }

Comment: Hope this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41646542/how-do-you-compare-just-the-time-of-a-date-in-swift

Comment: Use `Date` and `Calendar`class to achieve this as you cannot compare 2 strings for _Time Based comparison_ . However , if you really want to compare 2 _Time Strings_ , you need to define you own logic (which might be a bit complex)

Comment: As already mentioned by others comparing date strings is the wrong and in case of AM/PM a very cumbersome way. The most efficient way is to use `Calendar` and compare `Date` or `DateComponents`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iOS, Apple provide compare function to compare to Date objects.
Please find the below code to compare time

```
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    formatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
    formatter.amSymbol = "AM"
    formatter.pmSymbol = "PM"
    let timeString = formatter.string(from: Date())

    let firstTime = formatter.date(from: "09:00 AM")
    let secondTime = formatter.date(from: dateString)


    if firstTime?.compare(secondTime!) == .orderedAscending {
        print("First Time is smaller then Second Time")
    }
```